# One loader for all activities

Tags: android, android-service

Im building an Android application. It parses a feed which is stored in a DB. Each activity of the app is able to get this data from the DB.

Every activity can also call the Service, and make it refresh the data. When this is done I would like to display a loader. While the Service is downloading, the user is still free to navigate between activities. My question is; how can I display a loader that runs in all activities the user navigates to?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you want to indicate the loading in every activity and when the service is finished loading you want to display the result independ from any activity the user is currently on? Am I getting this right?

Comment: The result is easy. I'll just send a broadcast from the service. When the service is done I just want to hide the loader.

Comment: Is that an answer to my question or did you solve your problem? I'm confused...

Comment: :) Sorry for that. No, I didn't solve my problem. How can I display a global loader? Can I invoke it from the service?

Comment: At the risk of being stated as stupid: Could define what you want the see when your saying `display a global loader`?

Comment: A loader that is displayed over all activities... I don't want it to block the UI-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would try to  do since it seems to be an uncommon task to me:

I would try to setup a translucent [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) which contains a progress indicator. I would trigger / dismiss this popup to be displayed / or not whenever there's a need to indicate the loading progress...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Im thinking of extending Application and store a boolean (like downloading). Then I provide each activity with a spinning loader which is shown as long as the boolean is true. What do you think?

Comment: This might be good too. This would imply that every activity should include that spinner in it's layout, check the flag on every resume, and also listen to the cancel event of loading. This seems not to be a global solution to me and it's a little bit messy but it would certainly do the job ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

- Place a "global loader view" in all your activities.
- When you start/return to an activity, fire an AsyncTask which will be used to handle updates of the global loader
- Override `onPreExecute()` to prepare the global loader (e.g. setting its state to the current level if the service has been downloading for a while)
- Override `onProgressUpdate()` and use it to update the state of the global loader by asking the Service for the current state (load percentage or something)
- In `doInBackground` you implement:

  ```
  while( service.isLoading() ) {
    publishProgress( service.getLoadPercentage() )
    // Maybe add a Thread.sleep() here.
  }
  ```
- Override `onPostExecute` to set the visibility of the global loader to View.GONE.

You might need to implement a way of killing the AsyncTask if the user switches away from the activity when the loading is not finished yet.